# Implement a custom loss function in Tensorflow BoostedTreesEstimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, boosting

I'm trying to implement a boosting model using Tensorflow "BoostedTreesRegressor".

For that, I need to implement a custom loss function where during training, the loss will be calculated according to the logic defined in my custom function rather than using the usual mean_squared_error.

I read in articles that this can be implemented using the interface, "BoostedTreesEstimator" by specifying a head. So, I tried to implement my model as follows:

```
#define custom loss function to calculate smape
def custom_loss_fn(labels, logits):
    return (np.abs(logits - labels) / (np.abs(logits) + np.abs(labels))) * 2


#create input functions
def make_input_fn(X, y, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
    def input_fn():
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X), y))
        if shuffle:
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(NUM_EXAMPLES)
        dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)  
        dataset = dataset.batch(NUM_EXAMPLES)  
        return dataset
    return input_fn


train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train)
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(dfeval, y_eval, n_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

my_head = tf.estimator.RegressionHead(loss_fn=custom_loss_fn)

#Training a boosted trees model
est = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesEstimator(feature_columns,
                                         head=my_head,
                                         n_batches_per_layer=1,  
                                         n_trees=90,
                                         max_depth=2)

est.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=100)
predictions = list(est.predict(eval_input_fn))
```

This code provided an error as follows:
 'Subclasses of Head must implement `create_estimator_spec()` or 'NotImplementedError: Subclasses of Head must implement `create_estimator_spec()` or _create_tpu_estimator_spec().

As I read in articles, create_estimator_spec() is used when we define a model_fn() when creating a new Estimator. Here, I do not want to create any new models or Estimators, I only want to use a custom loss function (instead of default mean squared error) when training where the training model should be equal to BoostedTreesRegressor/BoostingTreesEstimator.

It is a great help if anybody can give me some hint to implement this model.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't using numpy functions in your loss function--you cannot convert tensors to numpy arrays. Try replacing np.abs with tf.abs. You might be getting the NotImplementedError because your loss function is breaking.